# Counterexamples for p-Laplacian equations showing that $C^{1,\alpha}$ is the best regularity.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

It is well known that the weak solutions of p-Laplacian equations are $C^{1,\alpha}$. Do they have more regularity? I have heard that no more regularity can be obtained. But I can't find the counterexamples.

Comment: Here you can find a family of examples: http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/MATEMATICAIBEROAMERICANA_1989_05_01-02_01.pdf

Comment: You are welcome.